# Big O Notation- Finding the Complexity

Tags: java, data-structures, big-o

I'm working on a quiz- I got all right but the following snippet. Help me understand which notation this would be?

My selections are: O(n^2), O(n^3), O(nlogn), and O(n+n^2)

Snippet is:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
     System.out.println("hello");
   } 
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { // NOTE j < i here. 
       System.out.println("hello");
     }
  }
```

Comment: Also I had previously answered O(n^2) and that was incorrect.

Comment: It looks like n-squared to me.  Maybe someone else can explain what is going on. (Well, I suppose one other answer is "n doesn't matter because the process is IO bound," but that's likely not what they're looking for.)

Comment: I’m pretty sure the correct answer should be O(n^2) here. I don’t know why that was marked wrong.

Comment: Given that `O(n+n^2)` is an available answer, I would guess that is what they are claiming the answer is. But since big-oh is the asymptotic performance as n tends to infinity, the n isn't relevant: it *is* `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

The first loop is easy: the body runs exactly `n` times, so it's `O(n)`.

The second one requires a bit more thinking. It's clear that the outer loop runs `n` times, but how often is the inner loop body executed? The first time through the outer loop, we have `i == 0`, so the inner loop body is executed 0 times (`j < i` is false even for `j == 0`). The second time, `i == 1` so the inner loop body is executed 1 times. In general, it's executed `i` times, for `i = 0, ..., n-1`.

So the total number of executions of the inner loop body is, let's call it `S`, is `S = 0 + 1 + ... + n-1`. Now there's a nice trick to make that into a closed form equation. Write it down once, and then once more in reverse:

```
 S =  0  +  1  + ... + n-2 + n-1
 S = n-1 + n-2 + ... +  1  +  0
```

Then add the two equations together:

```
 S  =  0  +  1  + ... + n-2 + n-1
 S  = n-1 + n-2 + ... +  1  +  0
------------------------------- +
2*S = n-1 + n-1 + ... + n-1 + n-1
```

So `2*S` is equal to `n` times `n-1`. From this, we easily find `S = n * (n-1) / 2`. This can be rewritten as `S = ½*n^2 - ½*n`. In the big-O form, only the highest order term survives, and the constant `½` does not matter, so this is `O(n^2)`.

A more "handwavy" way to get the same result is: the inner loop runs, on average, `n/2` times (give or take one), and the outer loop runs `n` times, again giving `O(½*n*n) = O(n^2)`.

Combined with the `O(n)` of the first loop, which becomes asymptotically irrelevant compared to the `O(n^2)`, the expected answer is probably `O(n^2)`.

But note that technically `O(n+n^2)` is *also* correct because `O(n + n^2) = O(n^2)`. Again, the lower order term `n` does not matter asymptotically. Even `O(n^3)` is technically correct because `n^3` dominates `n^2`; however, the complexity is neither `Ω(n^3)` nor `θ(n^3)`.

Comment: I took my last quiz attempt and this answer was wrong as well. So I guess O(nlogn)?

Comment: Hmm, I thought Big-O was supposed to be the tightest upper bound, so O(n^3) would be out because O(n^2) is a better fit.  But I might be misremembering.

Comment: @tryingsomethingnew At this point I'm sure it's O(n^2).  I think you need to talk to the instructor.

Comment: @markspace No, that's big-theta you're thinking of. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations Although most of the time when people talk about the big-O they mean the tightest possible upper bound. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Use_in_computer_science

Comment: Yeah I am going to bring it up- something isn't sitting right. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(This is what I think, I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation but I wanted to throw this out)

The first loop is linear and thus has the complexity of just `O(N)`.

However, for the second/third loop, the second loop is a loop that loops `N` times. The inner loop will run `N/2` time because `j` is always going to be less than `i`, (and never equal). Thus, the complexity for these loops is `N(N/2)`, or `N^2/2`. Because Big O is a constant, `N/2` and `N - 1` are the same time, so we can also say that it is `N(N-1)`, or `N^2 - N`.

If we add both complexities together, we have `(N) + (N^2 - N)`, we get `N^2`. Thus the final result is `O(N^2)`.

Comment: This is what I think too.   However the OP said that was marked wrong.  Now I'm wondering if the actual problem was "didn't show work" or the answer was right but the calculations where not (i.e., guessing is marked wrong).

Comment: (However I think the inner loop has a complexity of N/2, not N-1.)

Comment: Unfortunately its just a multiple choice question- so no work shown needed. I'm so stumped because based on what I understand of the complexity I definitely would've thought O(N^2)

Comment: I may have calculated something wrong here. I thought it was N^2 but I may have messed up the O notation for the inner loop.

Comment: The inner loop runs `i` times, not `N-1` times, although the result is still correct because `i` is also `O(n)` :)